# /405050011390461/context1

Tags: 14.04, network-manager

After installing mir on Ubuntu 14.04 desktop network Connection shows `/405050011390461/context1`. Unable to delete this `/405050011390461/context1`. I am unable to connect to the internet. There is a dir at /var/lib/ofono/40505001139061.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: First click /405050011390461/context1. Then onle Delete Button will be enabled

Comment: It is a directory in /var/lib/ofono. The directory permission needs to be changed using chmod. Deleting the directory may not be good idea. The solution for the internet to work was found. The link is given below. Thanks for your response please.

Answer (score 1):

Used locate command to search the numbers:
locate / 405050011390461
It is a dir in /var/lib/ofono. Searched ask ubuntu. Found the solution at following link:
http://hich-em.org/2014/05/10/problem-in-my-3g-modem-connection-activation-failed-in-14-04/

Install the two programs by opening a terminal and enter:

```
sudo apt-get install modemmanager
sudo apt-get install usb_modeswitch
```

Internet is working